# Docker on M1: standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: exec format error

Tags: docker

I tried to create a docker image based on alpine, but whenever I try to run it, I get this error message: `standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: exec format error`.

Here's the basic Dockerfile that just runs an executable file:

```
FROM alpine:3.13.5
WORKDIR /usr/local/bin
COPY profiles-svc /usr/local/bin
EXPOSE 20002/tcp
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/profiles-svc"]
```

The `profiles-svc` is an executable generated by the `go build` command.

I did not notice this issue on my ubuntu laptop, happens only on the Macbook M1.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I'm running on the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @andresmafra Hey. I found but I'm not on my machine now, I'll try to update it soon.

Comment: @andresmafra posted the answer, hope it will help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that there are two different architectures. If you use `go build` command on M1, it will be `arm64`, so if you try to execute that on docker with, for example, alpine image, it will fail. To fix that issue, you need to build `amd64` based binary. Here's the command: `CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o out-amd64`. Now you can copy that binary to your Linux based dockerfile, build and run.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because the golang code compiled under **Linux arm platform** cannot be run under **Linux amd platfrom**; Similarly, the image built under arm platform will not run on amd platform. The solution is to add the — **platform Linux/AMD64 parameter** when building your images.

`docker build --platform linux/amd64 -t tag .`